# Qt Browser Can Not Open http://www.weibo.com/

Tags: qt, browser, webkit

I am learning Qt5.5, and try to beautify the browser example in Qt;I found that it can not open this url "http://www.weibo.com/", though other browsers can open it without any problem. Is there anybody who know why this website is so particular that the Qt browser can not open it and how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is error that you see?

Comment: Just blank on the page

Comment: I do not know why this website is so particular

Comment: That means all other websites work well ? Other Chinese websites also (using Chinese font) ? Debug and check what HTML is received by your browser, maybe it is using flash or something else you can't render.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the font, because other websites can be displayed in a  normal way, no matter they are English or Chinese websites. And I am pretty sure, flash is not a problem, for the reason that it can display flash video well; I guess this problem may  relate to SSL, but not sure yet.